# Listview item not Display in the Fragment Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, fragment

I have Navigation Drawer with Fragment. I want to Open Fragment on Navigation Drawer. No any Error comes in code but Listview Item Not Display in Fragment. Only Blank Page Display. Following Code. Plzz Help Me.

fragment_blank_fragment_trip2.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.administrator.vtsapplication.BlankFragmentTrip2">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
```

BlankFragmenttrip2.java

```
package com.example.administrator.vtsapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BlankFragmentTrip2 extends Fragment {
public BlankFragmentTrip2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ViewGroup vg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};
    vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_trip2, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

    ListView listView = (ListView) vg.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_trip2, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: remove the last line, I think that is returning an empty view. just return the `vg` and do not send `ViewGroup` as the method `onCreateView()`'s return type is only `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should use your `Fragment` as this. You are not returning your `View`.

```
public class BlankFragmentTrip2 extends Fragment {

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};

    public BlankFragmentTrip2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_trip2, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You for Reply. Its Work and My Problem was solve by using your code.. Thank you.